# Only permit authenticated access to S3 files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I develop a platform, where authenticated users can watch videos.

I use Amazon AWS for my infrastructure. I guess it is a good idea to keep video files in S3 buckets.

But S3 buckets can be private (and no users can see the files) or public (than all the people in internet can see the files, even not authenticated to my platform).

So how can I make only authenticated to my platform users access the video files, that are kept in AWS S3 buckets?

Or maybe S3 is not a good choice for such a task? Than what else would I use?

Answer (score 2):

By default, all objects in Amazon S3 are private by default. This is great because your data is secure.

There are several ways to provide access to objects:

- **Access Control Lists (ACLs)** on individual objects, if you want to make just a few objects public
- A **Bucket Policy** on a bucket, if you want to make the whole bucket (or part of a bucket) public
- **Pre-Signed URLs** if you wish to provide temporary access to an object

**Pre-Signed URLs are time-limited URLs that grant access to an object for a defined duration.** Typically, users request access to an object and the application then determines whether they are permitted access. If so, the application can generate the Pre-Signed URL using a few lines of code (no API calls required). The user's web browser will then use that URL to access the object. Once the expiry period passes, the URL will no longer provide access.

For example, imagine a photo-sharing website. When a user wishes to view their private photos, the application can generate `<img />` tags with the pre-signed URL. The user will see their images as normal, but nobody else will be able to access their image files.

See: [Share an Object with Others - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)